# Entity Framework Core add multiple rows with Unique check

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm adding multiple new rows in a loop to the database and then saving changes. But I have a unique index accross 3 columns, so I need to check that they don't exist first to prevent exception.

The problem is, rows I add to the context are not found until after `SaveChanges()`, and so the duplicate check doesn't work. And so after adding all the rows, when I do `SaveChanges()`, I get a duplicate exception.

```
foreach (var row in json["data"]["animals"])
{
    var newRow = new Animal
    {
        Prop1 = row["prop1"].ToString(),
        Prop2 = row["prop2"].ToString(),
        Prop3 = row["prop3"].ToString(),
    }

    if (db.Animals.Where(p => p.Prop1 == newRow.Prop1 && p.Prop2 == newRow.Prop2 && p.Prop3 == newRow.Prop3).FirstOrDefault() == null)
    {
        db.Animals.Add(newRow);
        // db.SaveChanges(); // If I put this here instead, it works (no duplicate exception)
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();  // This throws the duplicate exception
```

Do I have to save the changes after adding every row? Or am I missing a better way to do this, because this seems inefficient/not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option without pre-filtering the json would be to add the new rows to a new collection, and check for duplicates in that at the same time as in the db, like this:

```
var added = new List<Animal>();
foreach (var row in json["data"]["animals"])
{
    var newRow = new Animal
    {
        Prop1 = row["prop1"].ToString(),
        Prop2 = row["prop2"].ToString(),
        Prop3 = row["prop3"].ToString(),
    }

    if (db.Animals.Where(p => p.Prop1 == newRow.Prop1 && p.Prop2 == newRow.Prop2 && p.Prop3 == newRow.Prop3).FirstOrDefault() != null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (added.Where(p => p.Prop1 == newRow.Prop1 && p.Prop2 == newRow.Prop2 && p.Prop3 == newRow.Prop3).FirstOrDefault() != null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    added.Add(newRow);
    db.Animals.Add(newRow);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because yo have duplicate values in your json data animals, first clean duplicate rows in your list:

```cs
// Linq is required
// using System.Linq;

// Map your json to a animal queryable;
var animals = json["data"]["animals"].Select(row => new Animal {
       Prop1 = row["prop1"].ToString(),
       Prop2 = row["prop2"].ToString(),
       Prop3 = row["prop3"].ToString()
   });

// Select only unique values
animals = animals.GroupBy(a=>new { a.Prop1, a.Prop2, a.Prop3 }).Select(a => a.First());

// Your logic to insert
foreach (var newRow in animals)
{
    if (!db.Animals.Any(p => p.Prop1 == newRow.Prop1 && p.Prop2 == newRow.Prop2 && p.Prop3 == newRow.Prop3))
    {
        db.Animals.Add(newRow);
        // db.SaveChanges(); // If I put this here instead, it works (no duplicate exception)
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();  // This throws the duplicate exception
```

Comment: I guess something like this is required. The Linq query on the db context just doesn't pick up the newly added-to-memory rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the equals method in your Animal class and compare the fields to avoid the duplicates:

```
public class Animal {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
      Animal animal = (Animal) obj;

      if (animal == null)
      {
        return false;
      }

      //Compare the values we care about except Id! 
      return this.Prop1 == animal.Prop1
        && this.Prop2 == animal.Prop2
        && this.Prop3 == animal.Prop3;
    }
}
```

Now you can see if any existing `Animal` object using Equals override:

```
foreach (var row in json["data"]["animals"])
{
   var newRow = new Animal
   {
       Prop1 = row["prop1"].ToString(),
       Prop2 = row["prop2"].ToString(),
       Prop3 = row["prop3"].ToString(),
   }

    var existedAnimal = db.Animals.SingleOrDefault(x => newRow.Equals(x));

    if(existedAnimal == null){
         db.Animals.Add(newRow);
         db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else{
       //You can throw some exception. 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this still requires saving the db changes after every Add(), and main problem I wanted to solve was avoiding doing that.

Comment: Oh I see, then I am upping the above answer.